# If else statement in Php url redirection

Tags: php, arrays, session

Hello I am working on project for online shopping in Php. I have designed a cart with a condition that if user is logged in he can add items in his cart else he will be redirected to the log in page.but as i am using array to join my syntax's I am not able get the required output.My code is as follows:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/mysql.class.php');
// Include database connection
require_once('inc/global.inc.php');
// Include functions
require_once('inc/functions.inc.php');
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$output[] = '<ul>';
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
$output[] = '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" by </br> '.$row['author'].': &pound;'.$row['price'].'<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />
.if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {. 
<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>'
.}
else {.
'<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>'
};
//$output[] = '</ul>';
echo join('',$output);
?>
```

Comment: you can not do this way..

Comment: what __exactly__ you want?

Comment: If user is logged in he can add items in his cart else he will be redirected to the log in page.

Comment: Your syntax is all messed up! Your using dots to concatenate strings with your logic, your missing braces. Think the answers below will fix it for you (although i don't neccassarily disagree with using an array and joining it at the end, that's generally a preference more s than a must). One thing to note is that you should probably instead use a check and redirect in your `cart.php` instead of relying on the links. Otherwise people could craft URL's to your cart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Youy code should be as follow:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$output = '<ul>';
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $output .= '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" by </br> '.$row['author'].': &pound;'.$row['price'].'<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />';
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) { 
        $output .= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        $output .= '<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>';
    }
}
$output .= '</ul>';
echo $output;
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
<?php
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);

$output[] = '<ul>';

while ($row = $result->fetch())
{
    if (isset($_SESSION['username']))
    { 
        $url = 'cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'];
    }
    else {
        $url = 'login.php';
    }

    $output[] = '<li>"'.
        $row['title'].'" by </br>'.
        $row['author'].
        ': &pound;'.
        $row['price'].
        '<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].
        '" width="100" height="100" /><br /><a href="'.$url.'">Add to cart</a></li>';
    $output[] = '</ul>';
}
echo join('',$output);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to create an output array, just create a string and add to that.

start with

```
$output = '';
```

and then replace

```
$output[] =
```

with

```
$output .=
```

and then you can do `echo $output;` instead of `echo join('',$output);` to output the value.

Answer (score 1):

Classic issue of missing ' at end of string literal and a use for the ternary operator:

```
$output[] = '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" by </br> '.$row['author'].': &pound;'.$row['price'].'<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />'
.  (isset($_SESSION['username']) ? 
      '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>'
      : '<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>'); // don't forget **;**
}
```

If you don't need this to be in an array, it would be better to pair this with the solution @GarethLuckett suggested: just concatenate the strings together, and no need for joining the array.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

```
$output = '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" by </br> '.$row['author'].': &pound;'.$row['price'].'<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />';
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$output.= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>';
}
else {
$output.='<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>';
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
   $link = (isset($_SESSION['username'])) ? "<a href="cart.php?action=add&id={$row['id']}">Add to cart</a>" : "<a href='login.php'>Add to cart</a>";
   $output[] = "<li> '{$row['title']}' by </br>{$row['author']}: &pound; {$row['price']} <img src='http://localhost/myproject/images/{$row['image']}' width='100' height='100' /><br /> {$link} </li>
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems, you have not closed while loop. Do like this:

```
<?php
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);
$output[] = '<ul>';
while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $str = '<li>"'.$row['title'].'" by </br> '.$row['author'].': pound;'.$row['price'].
    '<img   src=\"http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'\" width="100" 
    height="100" /><br />';
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $str .= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>';
    }
    else {
        $str .= '<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>';
    };
    $output[] = $str;
}
$output[] = '</ul>';
echo join('', $output);
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
<?php
require_once('inc/mysql.class.php');
// Include database connection
require_once('inc/global.inc.php');
// Include functions
require_once('inc/functions.inc.php');
session_start();
$sql = 'SELECT * FROM products ORDER BY id';
$result = $db->query($sql);

$output = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch()) {
    $data = '<li>'.$row['title'].' by </br> '.$row['author'].': &pound;'.$row['price'].'<img src="http://localhost/myproject/images/'.$row['image'].'" width="100" height="100" /><br />';
    if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
        $data .= '<a href="cart.php?action=add&id='.$row['id'].'">Add to cart</a></li>';
    } else {
        $data .='<a href="login.php">Add to cart</a></li>';
    }
    $output[] = $data;
}
//$output[] = '</ul>';
$output_string =  join('',$output);
echo "<ul>".$output_string."</ul>";
?>
```